# Dense, non-conductive UHV compatible material?

Tags: materials, vacuum

I'm not sure if this sort of question is appropriate here or not so please let me know if not!

I am designing a UHV vacuum system with a few interesting requirements. Inside of the vacuum chamber will be a multi-stage vibration isolation system consisting of masses sitting on springs (likely viton or other UHV compatible elastomer material). In addition, I will be using electromagnetic coils to create magnetic fields inside of the vacuum chamber.

The magnetic fields will be changing in times. This means that in general eddy currents can be induced in conductors. These Eddy currents create their own magnetic fields which can be problematic for my application and thus they are to be avoided. One way to avoid Eddy currents is to avoid conductive materials in the chamber.

The vibration isolation system will operate better if its natural frequencies are low. This can be accomplished by using larger masses.

If I wasn't worried too much about the Eddy currents/magnetic fields I would likely make the vibration isolation out of 316 Stainless Steel ($8 \frac{g}{cm^3}$).

However, I am curious if there is any non-conductive material which could be machined or formed into the appropriate shapes for my vibration isolation stage which also has a high density. For example, some ceramics I find have a density of $~3 \frac{g}{cm^3}$.

Does any one have a recommendation for a material which could suit my needs?

Other requirements:

- UHV compatible down to $10^{-11}$ torr
- Non-magnetic. In addition to not supporting Eddy currents the material should not become magnetized by the changing magnetic fields which are induced (magnitude of ~300 Gauss maximum)

Comment: I am a metals person, but you have got me wondering whether some ceramics might work for the stage. Manufacture by say slip casting, drying, and sintering. Chromite is fairly dense (4.5-5.1 g/cc), just make sure the purity is very high. Shouldn't offgas cause water is baked off. As for eddy currents I have no clue, might have to test.

Comment: Dang, chromite is weakly magnetic so it probably wouldn't work. Check out other dense ceramics though!